# What does `args` in Linux command `ps ao args` means exactly?

Tags: ps

In the man page of `ps`, I found that `-a` means:

> Select all processes except both session leaders (see getsid(2)) and
>   processes not associated with a terminal.

and `-o` means

> User-defined format.  format is a single argument in the form of a blank-separated or comma-separated list, which offers a way to specify individual output columns.  The recognized keywords are described in the STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS section below. Headers may be renamed (ps -o pid,ruser=RealUser -o comm=Command) as desired.  If all column headers are empty (ps -o pid=-o comm=) then the header line will not be output.  Column width will increase as needed for wide headers; this may be used to widen up columns such as WCHAN (ps -o pid,wchan=WIDE-WCHAN-COLUMN -o comm).  Explicit width control (ps opid,wchan:42,cmd) is offered too.  The behavior of ps -o pid=X,comm=Y varies with personality; output may be one column named "X,comm=Y" or two columns named "X" and "Y".  Use multiple -o options when in doubt.  Use the PS_FORMAT environment variable to specify a default as desired; DefSysV and DefBSD are macros that may be used to choose the default UNIX or BSD columns.

But what does the `args` means in this command?

Note the `args` is not a placeholder for anything else, just 4 chars: `a`+`r`+`g`+`s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting your question:

> The recognized keywords are described in the STANDARD FORMAT
>   SPECIFIERS section ...

If you look in that section:

```
CODE        HEADER    DESCRIPTION
...
args        COMMAND   command with all its arguments as a string.
                      Modifications to the arguments may be shown.  The
                      output in this column may contain spaces.  A
                      process marked <defunct> is partly dead, waiting
                      to be fully destroyed by its parent.  Sometimes
                      the process args will be unavailable; when this
                      happens, ps will instead print the executable
                      name in brackets.  (alias cmd, command).  See
                      also the comm format keyword, the -f option, and
                      the c option ...
```

There's more to the description in the manual, but this is the gist of it. Also note that for `ps`, options with and without a dash can mean different things.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS`, didn't find it before that.

Answer (score 0):

An *argument* or *command line argument*, is a file name or other data that is provided to a command in order for the command to use it as an input.

For example using the `wc` (word count) command, the arguments would be the file name. `wc story.txt`.